# convert outline to text in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

how can I convert an outlined text back to editable text in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: I don't think that's possible (I'd be curious to see otherwise). It's my understanding that there would be no way to map the line segments to a specific font (certainly not once you've altered them). You will probably need to manually change things, or throw out part (or all) of it and start from scratch.

Comment: do you know if i can at least detect wich font is used in the outlined object?

Comment: Maybe export as PNG and upload it to the My Fonts [font detector](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)?

Answer (score 3):

There is an OCR text recognition option in Acrobat that can do this.

- Save your illustrator text as a pdf compatible file ( Small chunks is best).
- In Acrobat select Document/OCR Text Recognition
- Select file and follow instructions
- Once done use the text tool in Acrobat to copy and paste your new editable text back into Illustrator.

The font style you can get by uploading your PDF file up to a web program like 'Whatthefont'

Comment: Hmm, cool. Does this OCR feature really work with vector paths, not just raster image data?

Comment: If it doesn't work for vector paths you can rasterize them youself. I wanted to OCR outline text in Acrobat but Acrobat's OCR first rasterized it to ~72dpi which looked awful and didn't OCR very well either. I opened the PDF in Illustrator, saved to PNG at 1200dpi, and OCR's in Acrobat and it worked great. I used the *ClearScan* option which builds a font from the OCRd letters and discards the raster so the file size was reasonable too.

Comment: OCR doesn't support all languages, so it won't work for non-latin based languages.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no can do. Once text characters have been converted to paths they're just that: paths. Illustrator has no memory of where you got them from. So, no, no font info either.

Answer (score 1):

I do this quite often, with a plugin from Astute Graphics called: VectorFirstAid. It usually finds the right font as well, if installed. This plugin can do some more tasks that are often needed, like reconnecting lines of text or versa versa / breaking them up in words.

Answer (score 0):

You need know what is the font in use from outline. Next, install the font in your operational system, then edit the text  and convert the font to outlines.

Comment: This seems like a less-complete version of MadMcin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to bring some update to this topic. You can recreate your text back as editable object directly within Adobe Illustrator using recently published extension that may perform text detection for your currently opened document regardless if it exists as part of bitmap or vector outline.

Let me introduce Krasbit Recognition. That extension includes also more features and is available at Adobe Exchange for free! Using the service also is free when you configure Google's API connection Key on your own. Otherwise you can use alternative connection API via trial or cheap prepaid codes.
https://www.adobeexchange.com/creativecloud.details.101113.html

See how it works at YouTube, starting 1':50"
https://youtu.be/DFDAiCFFWYg

Answer (score -2):

Just an update.

You can now do this with a plug in called TEXT RECOGNITION
FOR ADOBE® ILLUSTRATOR® from ESKO

https://www.esko.com/en/products/deskpack/plugins/text-recognition

You could also do this with an application called Hybrid Packz but there is a big price tag with that option.

But if you are on a budget then the OCR text recognition option in Acrobat will still a lot of the work for you. See the previous answers.